# Wordpress - is_home() and is_front_page() do not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set everything, including set the front page to "Home" page in reading setting, here is the screenshot:
[image]

And I added:

```
if( !is_home() && !is_front_page()) {
   echo "string";
}
```

But I still get "string" at the top of home page, as you can see in the screenshot.

Could anyone tells me why?

Thanks for any helps :-)

Comment: What is you actual code?  A string with content "string" can be coming from zillions of places.

Comment: @grochmal I only used `echo "string"` once which is where I was testing, and I just double checked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_front_page()` returns true if the user is on the page or page of posts that is set to the front page on `Settings->Reading->Front` page displays

So if you set about us as the front page then this conditional will only be true if showing the about us page.

`is_home()` return true when on the posts list page, This is usually the page that shows the latest 10 posts.

If the settings under Front page displays are left at default then the home page will return true for both `is_front_page()` and `is_home()`

An example of using `is_home()`:

- You have set your posts page to a page called News.
- A user navigates there and in the header you want to show additional
  navigation
- You could use `is_home()` to do this.

**Example:**

```
// Add below code in your functions.php
add_action('loop_start', 'Test_hook_check');
function Test_hook_check(){
    if( !is_front_page() ) {
        echo "string";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for explanation, and I have set the "Home" page to the front page, and it also shows "---- Front page" in the page section, and I have checked url it meets the page i was testing. I used `if( !is_front_page() ) {echo "string";}` but still get "string" at the front page...

Comment: Could you please explain where you have to put this code?

Comment: It is just for testing, because my is_front_page() does not work... I want to remove an action only in front page. I installed a plugin called 'theme-customisations-master' and put the code there @purvik7373

Comment: And I tried `wp_reset_query();` also, but it does not work... @purvik7373

Comment: I have update my answer, could you please check this?

Comment: yes it works!!! Could I know why? is that because I need to add the is_front_page() to a function and add it to the action? @purvik7373

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`is_front_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) for static pages.

Comment: Hi I did, I used `if( !is_front_page() ) {echo "string";}`, sorry it was a typo in the question.. But it did not work either.